# 2008 Suzuki gsxr 600 no power

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starting, power-loss, gsxr

Okay so I've been deployed for about three and a half months so my bike has not moved nor started for that long. When I got back I tried to start it and everything acted properly but nothing would turn over and I assumed it was a battery issue so I charged my battery back to full at cycle gear and then they did a test along with it and everything was fine. When I put the battery back in I now don't get any power at all. Right click the bike to on nothing happens and I am sure that it is a neutral along with the kickstand being up.
I have read that there is a history of the rectifier being bad which can mess up the charging system but that wouldn't make sense since before I charge the battery I was getting my lights to turn on.
I checked the fuse box next to the battery and everything is good there but I don't know if there's another fuse box that I'm missing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it sounds to me like your battery has gone bad,you should test the battery yourself by using a multimeter.what are the voltage before you try to start your bike,and what are the voltage with the engine running.

Comment: When you turn the ignition on do the lights (oil, neutral etc) light up?  What happens when you press the starter - do you hear any noises, do the warning lights dim? I would suspect the battery first as @trondhansen mentions

Comment: Reading again, it sounds like you're not seeing any warning lights after turning ignition on so it might be a blown fuse. You'd need to check the manuals or online to find out where fuses are.  I just found a forum post that says there's a main fuse under the tail. https://www.gixxer.com/threads/fuse-box-location.260741/

Comment: What does "everything acted properly" mean? Is this different to how it acts now since having your battery charged up?